# Exclude some fields while posting to Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have the following fields saved in my DRF.

1. Bio
2. Website
3. Phoneno
4. Gender
5. Avatar

I am using react-native as the front end. While updating the user profile I want to only post the changes to the server.But when posting to the rest api it is necessary to post all the values in the formData including the avatar and since the avatar has not changed I tried to pass the existing uri on the server which doesn't seem to work.
I tried creating another serializer and using PUT to pass data to the server which didn't work either. I keep getting the error.

"detail": "Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None"

Which I presume is probably because the uri passed is not valid. I have also tried using the get_validation_exclusions() method in the serializer but it doesn't work either. How do I make the posting of the avatar optional while updating all the other fields that have changed?

views.py

```
class ProfileView(APIView):
serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
def get(self, request, format=None):
    snippets = Profile.objects.filter(pk=request.user.id)
    serializer = ProfileSerializer(snippets, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = ProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        user= User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
        user.profile.bio=request.data["bio"]
        user.profile.website=request.data["website"]
        user.profile.gender=request.data["gender"]
        user.profile.phoneno=request.data["phoneno"]
        user.profile.avatar=request.data["avatar"]
        user.profile.save()
        user.save()
        return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def put(self, request, format=None):
    snippet = User.objects.filter(pk=request.user.id)
    serializer = ChangeProfileSeralizer(snippet, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        user= User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
        user.profile.bio=request.data["bio"]
        user.profile.website=request.data["website"]
        user.profile.gender=request.data["gender"]
        user.profile.phoneno=request.data["phoneno"]
        user.profile.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

```
class ChangeProfileSeralizer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Profile
       fields = ('website', 'phoneno','gender','bio')

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer): 
    avatar=serializers.ImageField(max_length=None,use_url=True)
    website = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    phoneno = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    gender = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    avatar = serializers.ImageField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('bio','website','phoneno','gender','avatar')

    def get_validation_exclusions(self,instance=None):
        exclusions = super(ProfileSerializer, self).get_validation_exclusions(instance)
        return exclusions +['avatar']
```

Edit(Profile Model):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
   bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
   website = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   phoneno = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   gender = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   avatar = models.ImageField('profile picture', upload_to='images/avatar/', default='/images/avatar/blank.png')
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `required=False`  on the avatar ImageField in the serializer, and then just excluding the field when posting the request?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the Avatar field to be readonly you have a two options.

**Option 1**

You can ensure that the ImageField is not required as said by @Ruben

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    avatar = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
```

**Option 2**

If the field is storing a string representation of the image and you plan on parsing it in the frontend then you can simply make avatar a [ReadOnlyField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#readonlyfield).

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer): 
    avatar = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using models from Django, then you need to change things

serializers.py

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 

        class Meta:
            model = Profile
            exclude = ('user',)
```

views.py

```
class ProfileView(views.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'profile', ProfileView)
```

and now you have access to your model directly

How it works you can look here:

[Model Serializer in DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer);

[Model Viewset](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset);

[Default router](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter)

Comment: Didn't work ends up giving the same error. {
    "detail": "Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None"
}  What do you think could be the problem?

Comment: Where you getting your Profile model from?

Comment: It is a one to one Field linked to the Django User Model. I have added it to the question check it out...

Comment: This will not work.  DRF will not allow you to specify both `fields` and `exclude`.